# RxFlow: how to implement deeplink navigation

Tags: ios, rx-swift

The app is tab based app using RxFlow for shaping the navigation. From deeplink I have an understanding of what Steps are needed to get to tab 1 and push VCs from there.

So, in my naivete knowing close to zero about the RxFlow (or RxSwift for that matter) I did

```
let steps = PublishRelay<Step>()
accept(foo)
accept(bar)
accept(baz)
```

Which resulted in zero changes to the UI. Nothing is happening.
Should I somehow use a composite stepper or flow contributors somehow?

In other words: how do you go to a screen X in RxFlow for deeplink purposes or restoring app UI state on restart.